# Move an element below or to the left of another element depending on the screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

This might be a silly but still worth asking.

Suppose I have the following:

**HTML**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 630px) {
  .left {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<!-- rectangle -->
<div id="red" class="left"></div>

<!-- paragraph 1 -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat auctor enim, finibus porttitor neque condimentum non. Maecenas finibus, ex sed vehicula vehicula, libero dolor maximus elit, eu posuere ex odio in mi. Cras ipsum dolor, lacinia
  nec tempus nec, luctus ut diam. Etiam pretium dolor a eros dignissim, vel tempus est condimentum. Phasellus fringilla condimentum arcu eget laoreet. Donec eget enim eget nunc volutpat rhoncus et vel tortor. Morbi tincidunt fermentum sapien sit amet
  euismod.
</p>

<!-- paragraph 2 -->
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent fringilla nulla id risus vehicula, vitae fermentum nisl varius. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, quis volutpat augue fermentum sit amet. Mauris vehicula lacus sed est tempor interdum. Fusce non fermentum metus, eget
  posuere lorem. Nulla facilisi. Ut laoreet justo sed neque aliquet, a ultrices nisi consequat. Suspendisse nec sem et metus fermentum venenatis vel a ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean interdum mi at lorem gravida, ac lobortis mauris mollis.
  Nulla eu metus erat. Phasellus et dui ex. Pellentesque nec lectus accumsan, ultrices nunc vitae, dictum sapien. Proin quis tortor tellus. Maecenas in sem eu enim mattis pellentesque.</p>
```

(1) On a big screen (e.g. >629px), it will float the rectangle to the LEFT of paragraph 1.

(2) On a small screen, it will obviously center and position the rectangle ABOVE paragraph 1.

My problem is with (2). **Without using JavaScript, is it possible to move the rectangle BELOW paragraph 1 but still ensure (1) ?**

--

If you look at this [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpexbE), resize the output window, the first rectangle appears in between the heading and paragraph on a small window.

My goal is to have all paragraphs either appear AFTER a paragraph on a small screen or LEFT/RIGHT on a big screen.

The only way so far that I can think of doing this is to have 2 copies of the rectangle (one before the paragraph, one after the paragraph) and use media queries to toggle between them. So I am just seeing if there is any other way.

Comment: If your page's direction is LTR, then by definition your element to the left must appear before the element on the right. Obviously the same applies for top and bottom, then I'm afraid your way is the correct way (and even if there is another way, it's probably irrelevant for over-complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use a flexbox around the elements and flip them that way.

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 630px) {
  .left {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<div class="container">
  <!-- rectangle -->
  <div id="red" class="left rectangle"></div>

  <!-- paragraph 1 -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat auctor enim, finibus porttitor neque condimentum non. Maecenas finibus, ex sed vehicula vehicula, libero dolor maximus elit, eu posuere ex odio in mi. Cras ipsum dolor, lacinia
    nec tempus nec, luctus ut diam. Etiam pretium dolor a eros dignissim, vel tempus est condimentum. Phasellus fringilla condimentum arcu eget laoreet. Donec eget enim eget nunc volutpat rhoncus et vel tortor. Morbi tincidunt fermentum sapien sit amet
    euismod.
  </p>
</div>


<!-- paragraph 2 -->
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent fringilla nulla id risus vehicula, vitae fermentum nisl varius. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, quis volutpat augue fermentum sit amet. Mauris vehicula lacus sed est tempor interdum. Fusce non fermentum metus, eget
  posuere lorem. Nulla facilisi. Ut laoreet justo sed neque aliquet, a ultrices nisi consequat. Suspendisse nec sem et metus fermentum venenatis vel a ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean interdum mi at lorem gravida, ac lobortis mauris mollis.
  Nulla eu metus erat. Phasellus et dui ex. Pellentesque nec lectus accumsan, ultrices nunc vitae, dictum sapien. Proin quis tortor tellus. Maecenas in sem eu enim mattis pellentesque.</p>
```

Comment: I will most likely not be able to use this solution because of browser support when it comes to flex -- maybe in a few years when people stop using old browsers. However, this does achieve my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really physically *move* the element below the paragraph just with CSS, but you can duplicate it and play with show/hide :

```css
.red {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
}

.left{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 630px) {
  .left {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
  .below{
      display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<!-- rectangle -->
<div class="red left"></div>

<!-- paragraph 1 -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque consequat auctor enim, finibus porttitor neque condimentum non. Maecenas finibus, ex sed vehicula vehicula, libero dolor maximus elit, eu posuere ex odio in mi. Cras ipsum dolor, lacinia
  nec tempus nec, luctus ut diam. Etiam pretium dolor a eros dignissim, vel tempus est condimentum. Phasellus fringilla condimentum arcu eget laoreet. Donec eget enim eget nunc volutpat rhoncus et vel tortor. Morbi tincidunt fermentum sapien sit amet
  euismod.
</p>

<!-- rectangle -->
<div class="red below"></div>

<!-- paragraph 2 -->
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent fringilla nulla id risus vehicula, vitae fermentum nisl varius. Nullam bibendum arcu risus, quis volutpat augue fermentum sit amet. Mauris vehicula lacus sed est tempor interdum. Fusce non fermentum metus, eget
  posuere lorem. Nulla facilisi. Ut laoreet justo sed neque aliquet, a ultrices nisi consequat. Suspendisse nec sem et metus fermentum venenatis vel a ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean interdum mi at lorem gravida, ac lobortis mauris mollis.
  Nulla eu metus erat. Phasellus et dui ex. Pellentesque nec lectus accumsan, ultrices nunc vitae, dictum sapien. Proin quis tortor tellus. Maecenas in sem eu enim mattis pellentesque.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper around each paragraph and rectangle pair and apply `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` to that wrapper on small screens:

```
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

On large screens you simply reset it to `display: block`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpVyQx